# How does switchMap() resolve a Promise?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I am going through the Angular 2 tutorial and I'm on the part about routers, specifically the part about using an Observable to extract the parameters from a URL.  It uses Observables for this.

Part of the code is this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
            .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    }
```

And the `getHero()` method:

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
        return this.getHeroes()
            .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }
```

As you can see, `getHero()` is strongly typed to return a Promise of type Hero.  It returns the result of a `then()` call, which, so far as I understand, is a Promise.

So `switchMap()` receives a Promise back.  As I understand the functionality of `switchMap()`, it takes whatever it is given and makes a new Observable out of it.  `subscribe()` then takes the value that Observable holds and assigns it to `this.hero`.

Here is what I don't get:  The `hero` instance variable is strongly typed to hold a `Hero` object.  Since `switchMap()` creates an Observable out of `getHero()`'s return value, and `getHero()` returns a Promise, it seems to me, then, that `subscribe()` is assigning a `Promise<Hero>` to `this.hero`.  I don't understand how that Promise is getting resolved and its actual value is getting extracted and put into the `hero` instance var.

Thanks to anyone who can shed any insight on this!!

Comment: AFAICT (I'm not an angular dev) a value of type hero will be set to that instance's `hero` property asynchronously when the Promise resolves via the `subscription` method. You will have to use the Observable to reliably access it though, simply trying to do member access could fail if the asynchronous operation has not completed.

Comment: Hum the thing I don't really get is that `switchMap` is not supposed to create a new Observable but to flatten nested ones. I didn't know switchMap could work with `Promise` and it doesn't seem to be documented http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap

Comment: What file and commit hash or link are you getting the `this.route.params.switchMap` from? I just cloned the project but I can't find that. It's now refactored and doesn't use switchMap.

Comment: Jared, so you are saying `subscribe()` auto-resolves Promises? Juan, this is part of the Angular 2 tutorial at www.angular.io

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's one of not very well documented features of RxJS 5. All operators that expect to receive an Observable from some callback work in fact with Observables, Promises, iterators, arrays, ...

Have a look at these:

1. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html
2. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~SubscribableOrPromiseDoc.html

So what happens is that `switchMap()` subscribes to the `Promise` returned from `getHero(...)` just like it was an Observable.

The core part of the source code is here:

- in `switchMap` - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/switchMap.ts#L108
- in `subscribeToResult` - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L42

A very common usage of this principle is when unpacking an array of items into separate emissions. For example:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4])
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

This will print:

```
1
2
3
4
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/sevale/4/edit?js,console

It works even though according to the manual [`concatAll()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll) works officially only with Observables emitting Observables.

Comment: So `subscribe()` here in fact resolves the Promise just like `then()` would?  Sorry, I am fairly new to this - I am teaching myself web programming, so I'm just starting to wrap my head around a lot of these concepts.

Comment: @steelstring94 This is completely unrelated to the `subscribe()` method. It's the `switchMap` who is responsible to handle the return value from its callback `(params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(...)`. The fact that it returns a Promise instead of an Observable is not a problem because `switchMap`s internals are designed to handle this usecase.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it, at least basically.  Thank you!!