# Does rxjs tap operator support async function？

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

my example code is

```js
    this.urls$.pipe(
      map(async (val) => {
        return await http.get(url);
      }),
      tap(async (val) => {
        const res = await val.res;
        console.log(res);
        return ture;
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

but i got a eslint message.

Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.eslint

how can i avoid this？

Comment: Why do you even `return` from a `tap` callback in the first place?

Comment: You should not use async/await with Observables. I suggest you read some introduction documentation around Observables.

Comment: You can use just `switchMap((val) => http.get(url))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awaiting a promise within map, you could convert the promise to an observable and use `switchMap` (or simelar) operator.

```
this.urls$.pipe(
      switchMap((val) => from(http.get(url))),
      tap((val) => console.log(val.res)),
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: You won't even need the `from` operator as `switchMap` can handle the promise straightforward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784660/how-does-switchmap-resolve-a-promise